# Javascript retrieve String Array Value Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

i seems to be having problem formatting an array string provide by my ajax method. I been trying to put in the data value directly in userCoor but it came out as an array only it should be (please refer to the picture)

Can somebody tell me how am i suppose to format into an array provided in the picture

So data is returning a single array instead of a dimensional array so how am i suppose to change to make into a dimensional array

Thanks

Sample Code

```
$.ajax({
  url: "#",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    var userCoor = [
      ['300 Tanglin Halt Road, Singapore 148812', 1.3000, 103.8000],
      ['Temasek Poly, Singapore', 1.346753, 103.932577],
      ['Temasek Poly, Singapore', 1.346368, 103.932175]
    ];

    console.log(userCoor);

    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

Update

I have now change dataType to text and it returns as seen below now is how to convert this text to an array

Raw data from source

```
['300 Tanglin Halt Road, Singapore 148812',1.3000,103.8000],['Temasek Poly, Singapore',1.346753,103.932577],['Temasek Poly, Singapore',1.346368,103.932175]
```

The problem i am facing is that i hardcod in the userCoor it work but i retrieve in the ajax method it doesnt userCoor[data] it will give a single line array instead of 3 dimensional array

Here is a Sample of what it is Suppose[Two same String but second link not known to be an array](http://i61.tinypic.com/10pu9v7.png)

Comment: May be your data is string.Try this
`console.log(JSON.parse(data));`

Comment: @Ninad i have this error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: data is not a JSON, is a string. What do you use to build json?

Comment: data is neither a JSON that can be parsed, you can't use JSON.parse

Comment: You receive from ajax code in a string rigth ?   Then you want to convert it to an array ?

Comment: i now have this string ['300 Tanglin Halt Road, Singapore 148812',1.3000,103.8000],['Temasek Poly, Singapore',1.346753,103.932577],['Temasek Poly, Singapore',1.346368,103.932175]

want to make into a dimensional array

Comment: Is raw data a string ??? If thats the case my solution should works.. why dint work for you, what is the error that you get with my solution? I,m just afraid that I cant understand what you want..

Comment: @rahpuser i tried urs its correct but why isit come out one array only i need the others so it be like Array[3] ...

Comment: @DanvinLeeQicheng sorry, I didn't tested, I was on the phone, but try it again, I fixed. Let me know if that is what you are looking for. regards

Comment: @rahpuser thanks you appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** using eval is considered evil practice.. **

if you are getting the string of the picture: "[bla bla bla],[bla bla bla]"..

you only need to do the following to convert that into a dimensional array:

```js
 var data = "['300 Tanglin Halt Road, Singapore 148812', 1.3000, 103.8000], ['Temasek Poly, Singapore', 1.346753, 103.932577], ['Temasek Poly, Singapore', 1.346368, 103.932175]";
 var result = eval('(['+ data +'])');

console.log(result);
```

This works for you ?
I'm just wondering why you receive that string from the server? maybe if you need an array you should change your server method..

Comment: nope it didnt work erm what i want to achieve and puzzle me is  when i hardcoded the string given to me it work perfectly but when i use a ajax method it didnt work